# How to click a link under drop down menu? cefsharp?

Tags: javascript, html, menu, cefsharp

For example I have been using this code to click automatically a button in a website using cefsharp:

```
chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('downloadBtn').click();");
```

I tried chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('treeNode-yui_3_18_1_1_1476978294430_2076').Selected = true;"); Not working

Now I need to click on the menu item. How to do that in cefsharp? It is not working with the code above?

Here is the HTML

[image]

Comment: As this is more a question of `javascript + html` I'd suggest adding some more tags to your question. `CefSharp` simply executes the code. Any code that will work in `Chrome` will be fine. So expand your search to find an answer. Just saying a `Menu` is vague as they can be implemented in so many different ways

Comment: Which element has the click handler registered? The `div` or the `span`? Call click on which ever one does, use some trial and error if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim MyClick As String = <js>
            document.getElementById("treeNode-yui_3_18_1_1_1476978294430_2076").click();            
                        </js>
    
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(MyClick)
```